# Positioning a view under navigation bar iOS 11 safe area

Tags: swift, swift4

I've been trying to position a view with UI elements under a navigation bar - that means to the top edge of the safe area. This works when navigation bar is not there, but once I add it, the safe area decreases in height and the view constraint to the safe area top edge is shifted to the bottom of the bar.

My question is: How can I programmatically shift the view so it overlaps with the navigation bar and is just under the status bar like it would be without the navigation bar?

Comment: What have you tried?  How is everything setup?  More information is needed to help you out.

Comment: Your question is confusing. It works when the navigation bar is not there but when the navigation bar appears then the view is attached to the bottom of the bar (which is what you want, isn't it?)?

Comment: This question is simple and clear, previous 2 commenters just didn't read it. This guy wants to know how to show view under Navigation Bar in iOS 11 where `edgesForExtendedLayout` not work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

First of all put your view where you want, and then you can animate your view constraints. Just drag and drop you constraint into your ViewController.
This example is for a view that move upside:

Outlet from constraint:

```
@IBOutlet weak var logoConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then when the view is appeared:

```
self.logoConstraint.constant = -180
```

You can also take a look here:

https://savvyapps.com/blog/advanced-ios-animations-with-auto-layout

Answer (score -1):

You can user 'superview' constraints. Top superview constraint is the top of the screen (where status bar starts) (it's 'View' in my screenshot).

[image]